# CSS Rotate overflows to other elements

Tags: html, css, rotation

I have the following map, [image]

and I am creating tables to represent these matrixes:

[image]

I am using the following rotation method:

```
.rotate {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(270deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}
```

Unfortunately when I rotate the top matrixes, I am getting my top matrixes overflowing to the bottom matrixes. You can see them overlapping between H2S-M1 and H2N-M1

Does anyone here have experience as to how I can fit everything nicely similar to the map provided?

Please take a look at my JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/27xyA/

Note that I have tried the method described here: http://kizu.ru/en/fun/rotated-text/ but the solution doesn't apply to non text objects.

Comment: You had some html markup errors, I've corrected that. http://jsfiddle.net/27xyA/1/

Comment: @dualed clarified wording

Comment: I don't see this in Chrome or Firefox. Anyway, you should rotate the contents of the cells instead of the whole tables, this should work out better and is easier to write in HTML/CSS.

Comment: @dualed if you are testing this in jsfiddle you should drag the viewing area to be bigger. And yes I am rotating the contents of the cell which happens to be a table as well

Comment: @disappearedng I see. Well my previous suggestion still stands or do it as SVG as this format is probably better suited for such output.